# Orientdb: Warning Msg Your maximum heap size is 3.54GB

Tags: java, orientdb

Suddenly, I got this warning message at the console:

**WARNING: Your maximum heap size is 3.54GB, but OrientDB uses off-heap memory to avoid GC pauses. In the case OrientDB is running as standalone, we recommend to use smaller amount of heap memory to let OrientDB using the rest as off-heap. 512 megabytes is recommended value of heap size.**

I went through config documentation and found a lot of possible system.params for instance:
**file.mmap.maxMemory**
**memory.optimizeThreshold (deprecated)**
and so on, but I have no idea how to set this value.

can you please specify what is the correct (near) value for a busy server with many instances of orientdb?

thanks

Comment: I do not know about OrientDB. But if you could tell me how it is started, I might be able to help.

Comment: Most likely this aims at the configuration of the VM its running in. Find the script that starts the thing and add -Xmx512m to the java invocation creating the VM (it may be possible to add this indirectly through a config file, consult the documentation when in doubt)

Comment: In 2.0-SNAPSHOT we completely changed the message to be more helpful: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2991

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message is a little bit confusing.

1) If you run OrientDB as a standalone server process, this message makes sense. OrientDB does not need a lot of heap memory and the (remaining) off-heap memory can be used for most of the DB paging. You can set the heap size by the `java` parameter `-Xmx512M` while starting up OrientDB.

2) If you run OrientDB embedded, this message is not really useful, because OrientDB does not know anything about the rest of your application. As long as you have enough off-heap memory it is fine and you can ignore the message.

3) This message is only displayed if you do **not** specify the (java system) property `storage.diskCache.bufferSize`.